# Hypnotic dotted spiral

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does someone know how i can create such a beautiful hypnotic dotted spiral in adobe illustrator?
Many thanks!
Best regards,
Silvan

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: I should think [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/150281/89608) already given to your other question will get you part of the way towards recreating such a design. All you really need is a dotted brush, applied to a curved path, and then rotate and duplicate the curved path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean exact similar pattern, I'd use `Object > Transform > Transform Each`:

First create a tiny dotted circle using dashed stroke, like this *(it would be inner most part of the pattern)*:

[image]

Then in the *Transform* window, do settings like this. **Basically, you need repeated rotation and scaled copies of innermost circle.**

[image]

Click **Copy** and press **OK**. Press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> for repeating the same, until you get a pattern.

[image]

[image]

You can use a radial gradient shape in the center later. You can use clipping mask if you want to crop the pattern.

Comment: Great, thanks for this solution! that helps a lot. But if I want the smallest dots to be larger, then I simply lower the scale to 105% for instance? Because the smallest dots are a bit too small now

Comment: @Silvan You can try. I chose that scale because I wanted to create something like your example. But keep in mind if you decrease scale, the dots will touch each other with current settings. If you want the smaller dots larger, you have to decrease the number of dots in the base circle and increase stroke weight. Then adjust Transform settings and proceed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I need to try that, because the smallest dots should ideally be in the size of about 1 pts and they should not overlap. I hope that this will work by decreasing the number of dots and increasing stroke weight. Besides that, I could also try to reduce the number of circles inside the spiral? that should also help to avoid overlapping...

Comment: @Silvan *I could also try to reduce the number of circles inside the spiral*: Yes. This is basically affected by those Scale values. more the scale, more space between each circle. Secondly, you'll need to experiment these settings. Experiment with stroke weight, number of dots in each circle etc and those Transform settings. The more you understand how it works, more easier will be for you to achieve desired result.